# How do I install MS Office 2010 via Wine?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I am trying to install MS Office 2010 on Ubuntu 12.04 on my new MacBook Pro (15").

I already read and followed every existing threads on forums and followed every existing tutorial, but my problem seem unique so far, since whichever solution I try, the problem remains.

When I launch PlayOnLinux, two boxes appear one after the other (before the latest upgrade of Ubuntu of last week, the second box did not appear, only the first one did);
the first one tells me:

> Error: PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32-bits OpenGL libraries. You
>   might encounter problem with your games."

When I close this window, a second one pops up, stating:

> Error: PlayOnLinux cannot find 7z. You should install it to use PlayOnLinux.

Of course, I tried purging PlayOnLinux (uninstalling it and re-installing it). I also tried other versions of PlayOnLinux. Nothing matters: the problem remains.

I did not succeed so far to install 32-bits OpenGL libraries, since I have a Radeon graphics card (which seems to be unusual) and I just cannot find these libraries.

Once the two "error" boxes are closed, PlayOnLinux is open, but does not seem to work properly; when I try to install Microsoft Office 2010, nothing happens.

When I try to close PlayOnLinux, it is even worse: Unity seems unable to close it (I even had a frozen screen when trying to  `xkill` it through the terminal).

I am looking forward to any tips that could help.

```
P.S.: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]
```

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 2):

For the second error, you need to install 7zip I think.

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to *also* install the `p7zip-full` package.

Comment: `p7zip-full` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Wine 1.6. No need for PlayOnLinux.

Tutorial here: http://blog.z-proj.com/microsoft-office-2010-professional-pro-on-wine-1-6/